# Upload file to an external API using Python Lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send a multipart/form-data POST request from an AWS lambda function to an external API containing a pdf file.

The client to lambda file upload works, and I can print the buffer content to the console.
The part that doesn't work is the file forwarding to an external API.

This is what i have been trying:

```
import json
import urllib3
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import base64

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    encoded_body = base64.b64encode(event['body'].encode('utf-8'))
    
    # multipart_string = "--ce560532019a77d83195f9e9873e16a1\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"author\"\r\n\r\nJohn Smith\r\n--ce560532019a77d83195f9e9873e16a1\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"file.txt\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\nExpires: 0\r\n\r\nHello World\r\n--ce560532019a77d83195f9e9873e16a1--\r\n"
    # content_type = "multipart/form-data; boundary=ce560532019a77d83195f9e9873e16a1"
    # dec = decoder.MultipartDecoder(multipart_string, content_type)

    url = "https://app.hubspot.com/api/filemanager/api/v3/files/upload?portalId=XXXXXX"
    
    payload={'options': '{"access":"PUBLIC_NOT_INDEXABLE"}',
    'folderPath': '"postman_upload"'}
    # files=[
    #   ('file',('file.pdf',open('/Users/Downloads/file.pdf','rb'),'application/pdf'))
    # ]
    
headers = {
      'cookie': '_conv_r=s%3Awww.yahoo.com*m%3Aorganic*t%3A*c%3A; hubspotutk=549ddd47f01a08d6f999bf4e85615f42; __hssrc=1;',
      'x-hubspot-csrf-hubspot': 'AAccUftoNFPKG7PGr6tcWR7JA6Rt35lR4D7qCRL3HcK3deuw23-ucJy4oQvE0dYI43bfP2CCKiZM0j7a03XmaC6hy46ExFlA5g',
      'authorization': 'Bearer pbl-na1-c23b6031-7da9-4e7d-9516-6c58vc7cd0dc'
    }
    
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files) #TYPE-1

    print(response.text)

    response = requests.request("POST", url,headers=headers, data=event['body'].encode('utf-8')) #TYPE-2

    print(response.text)
      
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': encoded_body
    }
```

But with this when I send the post request I get "415 Media Type not supported" response.
As the pdf/file is being sent as json (bytes) in the request body but it should be just form data with the parameters.

I am not able to achieve that, have already tried many approaches but none worked.
And most of the folks here are uploading the file to S3, which is typically easy. [But I want a post req with multipart file to an external API]

If anyone here has any idea for this or what I am doing wrong. Could you please help. Thanks.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you have an endpoint receiving file as multipart POST request and you have the file content via lambda event handler. I think `requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, files={"file": StringIO(event["body"])})` should work in this case.

Comment: Hey @BijayRegmi first of all really thanks! With your approach the file is getting uploaded. 
But Still there are 2 issues I observed:
- When I preview file its not the pdf which i uploaded but its the binary version of it. PFA [screenshot](https://ibb.co/xjPhf0f)
- The file was uploaded without an extension,I tried adding ".pdf" extension by renaming it, but the result was a blank pdf.

sample [req_body](https://ibb.co/nmvkhgh)